# Getting address of variable using baseaddress and offsets

Tags: c++, windows, memory, windows-kernel

I am trying to get the address of a global variable from a target program. I can get the baseaddress of the target program using PsGetProcessSectionBaseAddress.

Target Program Code:

```
#include <iostream>

MyType myObject;

int main(){
    ...
}
```

How do I get the offset of myObject (I can't figure how with offsetof because it requires a type for the variable to be inside of), and once I get the offset can I just add the offset to the baseaddress to get the address of the variable since it's global?

Comment: you can not do this. maximum what you can - search location of `myObject` if this possible. or program must by self tell you about address of `myObject`. say pass it to your driver in some ioctl

Comment: RbMm should I try passing the addresses to the driver or should I try using shared memory?

Comment: i can not know this. depend from your task and situation. if you write exe where `myObject` - you know it address - simply `&myObject`. if this is not your src code - in general impossible get address of internal object, if it not exported. and unclear for what this is for driver

Comment: both are my source. The driver is supposed to read myObject from memory using it's address and if one of it's members is a certain value, the driver does something

Comment: if both you - simply pass `&myObject` to driver

Answer (score 0):

By offset, do you mean address of? Just use the address of operator `&` in that case. If you mean offset from base address it's just a basic subtraction of `n = (addr - base_addr)`.

Comment: I think OP really means [offsetof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof).

Comment: Offset meaning offset from base address

Comment: Ted is correct, how do I get the offsetof a variable which is in a global scope

Comment: It's just basic subtraction then. Grab the base address of your module, address of object, and subtract to get the rva (relative virtual offset).

Comment: You can't. The ``offsetof`` macro is for getting the offset of a field within an object, not getting the offset of an object within an image which is what you want.

Comment: And then after that I can just do the baseaddress plus the rva to get the address of the variable?

Comment: No, you don't understand. That macro just gives an offset to a defined field within that objects structure. To get the RVA it's just (obj_addr - img_base_addr).

Comment: I wasn't talking about the macro -_-